# Как передать Тг-боту эксель файл на Python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пока что без использования бота, чисто в коде, есть такая строчка:

`shop_stock = pd.read_excel('PriceTiss.xls', header=5)`

Можно как-то в тг-боте сделать так, чтобы этот файл я скидывал ему в чат и он подставлял его в это место?

Comment: Ну а в чем проблема? В библиотеке pyTelegramBotAPI есть возможность обработки входящих сообщений с прикрепленным файлом. Данный файл можно скачать (во временную директорию или постоянную по необходимости), а потом читаете его в датафрейм.

Comment: И какая разница, .xsl это файл, или, скажем, .txt?